# error appear when I execute a SQL request

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL request that I can't execute ,this error appear:
    **To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor   and reconnect.
You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column**

My request:

```
update customfieldvalue
set stringvalue="****"
where customfieldvalue.customfield IN 
(select customfield.id 
from customfield 
where customfield.cfname="Resoltion" 
and customfieldvalue.issue=12345);
```

how can I fix this problem,because in my production environment I can't do this manipulation?
PS:I'am using mysql

Answer (score 2):

To disable it just for the current session run:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem:

*To disable safe mode:
Toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.*

The cause:

*You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column*

(Did you read the message?  It explains everything)

Comment: yes I did read the message, in matter fact ,this error is in my test environement, and I will execute this request in my production environement on wich I can't do this manipulation

Answer (score 0):

If you can't turn off safe update in production, you'll need to rework your query to involve at least one key column in `customfieldvalue`.  Without it, you'll be performing a table scan; using key column #1, you might end up with the logical equivalent ( `WHERE customfieldvalue.keycol1 IS NOT NULL` ), but that will satisfy the safe update constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
update customfieldvalue
set stringvalue="****"
where customfieldvalue.customfield IN 
(select customfield.id 
from customfield 
where customfield.cfname="Resoltion" 
and customfieldvalue.issue=12345);
```